# Which word – 'leap, spring, bound (etc)' – is most appropriate for a single jump?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request

> In one leap, she sprang up on her desk, nimble like a cat.
>
> In one spring, she sprang up on her desk, nimble like a cat.
>
> In one bound, she sprang up on her desk, nimble like a cat.

I'm trying to figure out which of these words is best to use, especially when I want to emphasize that it's taking just *one* step to get from the floor to the desk. Are they all essentially the same in that regard, or would any of these words not be good to use in this context?

Comment: I think its already implied by using "sprung up on her desk" that its in one action (can't imagine otherwise).  So in my opinion the first phrase "In one leap" etc. is not necessary. "In one spring" is definitely repetative. I would put in a phrase that adds additional or contasting information, for example "From out of nowhere, she sprang up on her desk, nimble like a cat."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me, *leap*, *bound* and *spring* have slightly different emphasis compared with the more neutral noun *jump*. At least to my ears:

- a **leap** emphasises the *distance*, or *gymnastic ability* of the jump.
- a **bound** emphasises the *energy* or perhaps the *enthusiasm* of the jump.
- a **spring** emphasises the *speed* or the *unexpectedness* of the jump.

So for example, I might use them in the following sentences:

> The cat **leapt** into the air, and landed on the next door neighbour's balcony.
>
> When Joe came home, he was met with Bruno the dog, who **bounded** through the hallway and jumped up to greet him.
>
> When Mary stepped on the cat's tail, he **sprang** up and scratched her.

In the context of your sentence, where the emphasis is on the *nimbleness* and perhaps *distance* of the jump, I would therefore choose *leap*, although I would avoid mixing *leap* with *sprung*, instead preferring a more neutral noun to go with the verb *leapt* or a more neutral verb to go with the noun *leap*:

> In one **leap**, she **jumped** up on her desk, nimble like a cat.
>
> In one **quick movement**, she **leapt** up on her desk, nimble like a cat.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry my question wasn't clear. I wanted suggestions for 'in a single jump' in the first part of the sentence, not the verb. "In one leap/bound/spring"

Comment: @Soulz: I've changed my answer to more closely match your altered question.

Comment: @Soulz: When an answer isn't quite what you were looking for, that usually means you've asked a question with **not enough detail**. When you discover that happens, you need to **fix your question**, and not merely leave a comment to the answerer. Otherwise, many others will come here, read the question, and go down the same [rabbit trail](http://andtodaysidiomis.blogspot.com/2010/12/rabbit-trail.html).

Comment: @J.R. I guess you didn't noticed I added 2 more sentences with each option.

Comment: @Soulz: Even with those two additional sentences, it's still not clear what you're asking about, and your comment here was more enlightening than your additional sentences there. I've take the liberty to make an edit of my own to help you understand what I'm trying to say. Also, it wouldn't hurt to add a few remarks about what you found in a dictionary before you asked the question. That's something often considered to be a courtesy to include, if not a breach of etiquette to omit. The more effort you put into your questions, the more they will be appreciated and taken seriously.

Comment: @J.R. Thank your for the edit. It makes things clearer. I usually do the spadework before I ask questions. Only I thought definitions of the words in this instance were common knowledge.

Comment: @Soulz: No problem. It never hurts to add something like, "I know all these words mean 'to jump,' but I'm wondering if one of them might imply [_a higher/a more nimble/a more cat-like/a more sudden_] jump than the others." Such clarifications make your question easier to answer correctly, and more interesting to the community at large; they demonstrate you've given your question more serious thought; they serve as a good model for other users who come here and ask questions. It's rare to find a question that delves into _too much_ detail, but scant ones are unfortunately all too common.

Comment: @J.R. Good point. I will keep your words in mind. Thanks :)

Comment: Not a problem. Glad to help. I hope you stick around and keep participating.

Comment: Purely as a side note, I'd recommend using "as nimble as a cat" in place of "nimble like a cat". See the Ngram https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=nimble+like%2C+nimble+as&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cnimble%20like%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cnimble%20as%3B%2Cc0  "Nimble like" is a rare construction. Even better, I think, would be to use "catlike", as in "In one catlike leap,...".